# How can i get tornado error response in ember js action?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I wrote a search action in Ember.js for search results from Tornado server. Now the problem is when search not found any results I raise an error using `tornado.web.HTTPError(statuscode)`:

```
Server.py:
=========
          if not rows:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(400)
```

I'm trying to handle the error in my App.js file like this:

```
App.js:
========
      search: function() {
        // the current value of the text field
        var query = this.get('query');
        data = $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          url: "/search?query=" + query,
          async: false}).error(function(response) {
                           alert(response.responseText);
          }).responseJSON;
```

In above code when Tornado raises an error, `.error(response)` is executed, but `responseText` is empty.

How can I catch that error and redirect to an error page?

Comment: is the error page an ember route???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is not from EmberJS. Its in `Ajax Request`. You are requesting for `data-type` of JSON but for `404` you are sending HTML content(probably like this `<html><title>400: Bad Request</title><body>400: Bad Request</body></html>`) which after parsed returns empty. Either remove data-type as JSON from AJAX Request or write your own custom handler like this in server to return 404 error in JSON mode.

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.clear()
        self.set_status(400)
        self.finish("[]") //some JSON
```

Comment: Thank you... i miss that, now i change my code.its working fine